# array initialization requires a brace-enclosed initializer list

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, initializer-list

My class `Matrix4x4` has a constructor that takes 9 values and copies them into an internal `T value[4][4]` member through an initializer list. However, it doesn't compile, and I'm not entirely sure why. Specifically, the error says: `array initialization requires a brace-enclosed initializer list`.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

```
template<typename T>
Matrix4x4<T>::Matrix4x4(
    T aa, T ba, T ca,
    T ab, T bb, T cb,
    T ac, T bc, T cc
    )
    : value({
        { aa, ba, ca,  0 },
        { ab, bb, cb,  0 },
        { ac, bc, cc,  0 },
        { 0,  0,  0,  1 }
    })
{

}
```

Comment: How is `Matrix4x4::value` defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to a C++11 compiler, here's one solution.

Remove the `(` and `)` from the initializer of value. Use:

```
Matrix4x4::Matrix4x4(T aa, T ba, T ca,
                     T ab, T bb, T cb,
                     T ac, T bc, T cc)
   : value{ { aa, ba, ca,  0 },
            { ab, bb, cb,  0 },
            { ac, bc, cc,  0 },
            { 0,  0,  0,  1 } }
{
}
```